# Nicely motivated papers or book chapters on the formula for the sum of the $k$-th powers of the first natural numbers

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, heuristics, induction, bernoulli-numbers

Do you know of a text where I can find a nicely motivated proof of the formula for $1^{k}+2^{k}+\cdots+n^{k}$?

At the very beginning of page 68 of Professor H. S. Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf), one can find a pretty straightforward way to obtain it but, unfortunately, there aren't any comments there regarding the "sources" of the proof.

Comment: This seems more like [MESE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com), or [HSMSE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com), or maybe just [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com) material.

Comment: Haven't had good experiences with some of those sites...  In my experience, the quick and knowledgeable replies to this kind of questions can be obtained here.

Comment: Everyone avoids those sites because they feel that the community isn't the same as what we've got here, but that's what those sites are meant for.  Abusing MO for non-research math to get the answers that are given here just reinforces the lack of community at the more appropriate sites.

Comment: I think you will be able to find an agreeable proof in either https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.10831.pdf or Sums of powers of positive integers by Janet Berry, MAA Convergence, https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/sums-of-powers-of-positive-integers-introduction.

Comment: @Mark Wildon: Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Name of @MarkWildon's first [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391656/nicely-motivated-papers-or-book-chapters-on-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-the-k-t#comment998870_391656):  [Taylor - Faulhaber's problem revisited: Alternate methods for deriving the Bernoulli numbers—Part I](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.10831).

Answer (score 1):

G. Polya, Mathematical discovery.